# Parameter does not exist as a named parameter even if well named

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I have an issue that i can't solve.

Hibernate shows this :

```
Parameter targetDate does not exist as a named parameter in [delete from com.inetpsa.stb.model.Journal t where t.date < :targetDate]
```

targetDate is set as this :

```
public int purgeOrSave(String hql, Date targetDate) {
        Query query = getSession().createQuery(hql);
        query.setDate("targetDate", targetDate);
        return query.executeUpdate();
}
```

hql is a string containing the query to execute : "delete from com.inetpsa.stb.model.Journal t where t.date < :targetDate"

My entity is well defined. I have tried to suppress the fully qualified name of the entity as this :

```
delete from Journal t where t.date < :targetDate
```

and the result is that hibernate tells me that Journal is not mapped...

Any idea ?

PS : here is the code of Journal:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping package="com.inetpsa.stb.model" default-lazy="false">
   <class name="Journal" table="STBQTJEV">
        <id name="id" type="java.lang.Long" column="JEV_ID">
          <generator class="native">
           <param name="sequence">STBQXJEV</param>
          </generator>
        </id>
        <property name="uuid"           column="JEV_UUID"           type="java.lang.String"/>
        <property name="canal"          column="CAV_CODE"           type="java.lang.String"/>
        <property name="commandeId"     column="CMD_CODE"           type="java.lang.String"/>
        <property name="contratId"      column="CNT_CODE"           type="java.lang.String"/>
        <property name="contratClient"  column="CNT_CONTRAT_CLIENT" type="java.lang.String"/>
        <property name="vin"            column="VCL_VIN"            type="java.lang.String"/>
        <property name="clientCode"     column="CLT_CODE"           type="java.lang.String"/>
        <property name="clientMaile"    column="CLT_MAIL"           type="java.lang.String"/>
        <property name="evenementCode"  column="EVN_CODE"           type="java.lang.String"/>
        <property name="offer"          column="JEV_OFFER"          type="java.lang.String"/>
        <property name="produits"       column="JEV_PDT"            type="java.lang.String"/>        
        <property name="source"         column="JEV_SOURCE"         type="java.lang.String"/>
        <property name="step"           column="JEV_STEP"           type="java.lang.String"/>
        <property name="statut"         column="JEV_STATUT"         type="java.lang.String"/>
        <property name="commentaire"    column="JEV_COM"            type="java.lang.String"/>
        <property name="detail"         column="JEV_DETAIL"         type="java.lang.String"/>
        <property name="date"           column="JEV_DATE"           type="java.util.Date"/>       
        <property name="dateDebut"      column="JEV_DATE_DEBU"      type="java.sql.Timestamp"/>
        <property name="dateFin"        column="JEV_DATE_FIN"       type="java.sql.Timestamp"/>
   </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: Could you provide code for Journal entity?

Comment: Does it work with `setParameter()` instead of `setDate()`?

Comment: query string for starters

Comment: Have you tried: delete from Journal where date < :targetDate?

Comment: setParameter() does not work (same error as setDate).

Comment: delete from Journal where date < :targetDate does not work. I get an error telling that Journal is not mapped !

Comment: Is there a possibility, that you're passing null reference as parameter?

Comment: I have passed the code in debug and the value targetDate is well setted  (not null)

Comment: Have you mapped your entity Journal in your hibernate.cfg.xml file?

Comment: Yes I did. Extract of my hibernate.cfg.xml  :
        
<mapping resource="com/inetpsa/stb/model/Trace.hbm.xml" />
        <mapping resource="com/inetpsa/stb/model/TraceHisto.hbm.xml" />
        <mapping resource="com/inetpsa/stb/model/Journal.hbm.xml" />
        <mapping resource="com/inetpsa/stb/model/JournalHisto.hbm.xml" />
        <mapping resource="com/inetpsa/stb/model/CommandeTemp.hbm.xml" />

Comment: can it be a bug of my oracle jdbc ? we have done recently an upgrade to ojdbc6 / 12.1.0.1

Comment: What is the import of Date in the class where `public int purgeOrSave(String hql, Date targetDate)`is defined? java.sql.Date or java.util.Date? Your mapping requires java.util.Date, maybe your IDE imported the other one.

Comment: it could have been this, but targetDate is a java.util.Date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After calling our team expert, the solution has been found. Our application manages 2 different sessions. The query was called on the bad one, which explains that Journal was "not mapped" for hibernate. After a correction on the caller of the dao, the batch works correctly. Thanks to everyone for your help.

Answer (score 0):

use

> query.setParameter("targetDate", targetDate)

instead of

> query.setDate("targetDate", targetDate)`

Comment: In comments upper, setParameter() does not work (same error as setDate).